# Programticly post a text with image on google plus wall/stream

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

All I want to post a text with `an image` on Google+ wall/stream using Oauth2 and PHP.  Similar to a wall post for Facebook and Tweet post for Twitter.

User click on `share on Google+` button from my website, they redirect to the google app approval page, they approve and message with the image get posted on their stream/wall.

I have searched almost entire internet for this requirement. But I didn't get exact code to achieve this.

I have already checked this: [Google APIs PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

However the code is not up to the point or clear.

Some people says that it is not possible, google only allows read operations.

But then some people says it is possible according to this: [Creating new posts and comments](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating)

Google documentation is very confusing for this requirement, compare to Facebook and Twitter.

So all I want is clear answer whether is it possible or not? If yes then how?

Answer (score 3):

The [google plus api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) is read only it does not support posting in any form.  [Google plus domains](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) is for posting to Google domains accounts not google plus the social media website.

> Develop business apps that integrate with Google+ With the Google+
>   Domains API, Google Apps customers and ISVs can build custom Google+
>   functionality and services for people who use Google Apps at college,
>   at work, or at home. Organizations can develop tools to interact with
>   Google+ features such as posts, comments, and circles. These tools let
>   your users share information, reinforce communications, and grow
>   productivity within your organization.

[Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/pages-signup) is for posting to Google+ page and is in closed beta.

There is no way to programmatically post to the [google+ social media website](https://plus.google.com/u/0/) wall/stream.  However there is a six year old issue request for it [Write access to the streams](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41&q=post&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).